# Multi Banco com Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, migrations

Tenho uma aplicação  C# e Entity Framework.
Eu preciso gerar uma migration para um banco sql server e uma outra para uma base de dodas Oracle

Alguém sabe se é possível gerar a migrations para cada db com apenas um contexto?

Grato!

Comment: @ronaldo-leite, provavelmente não seja possível cria uma única `migrations` para tipos de bancos diferentes com um mesmo `contexto`. Mesmo assim para afirmar corretamente precisamos de mais informações como por exemplo: - Qual é a versão do Entity Framework que você está utilizando? Você está na abordagem `CodeFirst` **( o código do banco é gerado através do código )** ou `DbFirst`? **( o código apenas mapeia uma base de dados existente )***

Comment: @William, obrigado pelo retorno rápido.
Estamos usando o EF 6 e a abordagem é CodeFirst.

Comment: @ronaldo-leite reforço parte do meu primeiro comentário: sem 2 *( um para Oracle e outro para Sql Server )* `contextos` você não vai conseguir fazer isso, logo você terá `migrations` do 2 tipos para gerenciar.